# Envie 10 valores usando o método POST, os valores deverão ser inseridos em um vetor

Tags: php, array, inserir

O objetivo é o seguinte: enviar 10 valores usando o método POST através do formulário, e inseri-los em um vetor, que posteriormente será impresso.

Quem puder me ajudar agradeço desde já.

Comment: Como assim vetor ? Os 10 valores que vai ser enviado pelo form você quer dentro de um array ? É isso ?

Comment: Tipo assim, tenho dois campo input no formulário, um tipo number e o outro submit, quando eu submeter quero que o número inserido no campo number vá para uma posição do array, cada novo número inserido em uma nova posição, e depois com o vetor já completo com os 10 números, imprimi-lo. Não sei se ficou muito claro...

Comment: Todo o código que já tem para o objetivo que indicou é util e por isso deve ser colocado na pergunta, focando na sua real duvida, no que não está a conseguir fazer nesse código.

Comment: Quando você submeter, o número que foi no input tem que ir a uma posição especifica no array ?

Comment: Não, vai ser inserido na contagem do próprio array, ex: digitei 23, vai para posição [0], digitei 78, vai para posição [1]....

Comment: Bem-vindo! Da proxima vez que fizer uma pergunta procure faze-la de acordo com esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: também seria interessante ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas dicas! da próxima vou tentar seguir mais o post indicado pelo Leo Caracciolo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com esse comentário do autor

<sub>"tenho dois campos input no formulário, um tipo number e o outro submit, quando eu submeter quero que o número inserido no campo number vá para uma posição do array, cada novo número inserido em uma nova posição, e depois com o vetor já completo com os 10 números, imprimi-lo."</sub>

Uma das formas de se obter esse resultado é usando sessions.

**PHP**

```
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST['num']) && isset($_POST['num']) ){ 

    //contagem do numero de vezes que o formulário foi submetido
    $_SESSION['dez']=$_SESSION['dez']+1;

    $numPost = $_POST['num'];

    if ($_SESSION['num']==""){
        $_SESSION['num'] = $numPost;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['num'] = $_SESSION['num'].",".$numPost;
    }

    if ($_SESSION['dez']==10){  
        $meuarray = explode(',', $_SESSION['num']);
        print_r($meuarray);
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
    <label><input type="number" name="num" value="" required><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```